# Media queries not overriding pre-set styles in Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I created a _mobile.scss to add responsive design to my website but some of my media queries are not overriding the default styles. I checked other posts on this topic which talked about 'specificity' but I made sure that the _mobile.scss is imported in the style.scss after the _home.scss (where I'm currently styling)

this is the content of styles.scss:

```
@import 'utilities/config';

@import 'layout/sidebar';

@import 'pages/home';

@import 'layout/mobile';
```

this is the _mobile.scss :
/

```
* Large screens */
@media  screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .navbar {
      top: 0;
      left:0;
      width: 8rem;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .navbar:hover {
        width: 20rem;
    }
    
    .navbar:hover .link-text {
        display: inline;
    }

}


 /* Small screens */

 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {


    .banner-wrapper{
      img{
        width:50%;
      }
    }

    .intro-text{
      
      h1{
        font-size: 2rem;
      }

      .typing::after{
        height:50%;
      }
    }

    .about-content{
      flex-direction: column;

      img{
        width:100%;
      }

      p{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
      }
    }


 }

 @media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar {
      bottom: 0;
      left:0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 5rem;
      z-index:1;
    }

    .logo {
        display: none;
      }

    
    
    .navbar-nav {
       flex-direction: row;
       width: 100%;
    }


    .nav-link {
        justify-content: center;
        height: 5rem;
        


        i{
          font-size: 2rem;
         
        }
    }
    
    main {
        margin: 0;
    }


}
```

And this is a portion of the _home.scss(the part that isn't working):

```
#banner{
  position: relative;
  top: -5rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.banner-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;


  img{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    
  }

  
  .intro-text{
    text-align: center;

    h1{
      font-size: 5rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    
    .typing{
      position: relative;
      margin-left:10px;
    }

    .typing::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      right: -2px;
      width:1px;
      height: 100%;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      animation: blink 0.5s infinite ease;
    }
  }
 
 }
```

Where I'm confused is that I am able to change the img width of the .banner-wrapper on small screens (less than 800px) but changing the font-size of the h1 and height of .typing::after in  .intro-text has no effect. So how can I fix this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking your code i found that in your _home.scss the .intro-text is wrapped inside .banner-wrapper whereas in your media query you're defining the .intro-text outside the .banner-wrapper double check it by defining the .intro-text inside the brackets of .banner-wrapper in the _mobile.scss and it might be the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that helped you.
Yea nesting in SCSS is very tricky at first glance i didn't noticed it because your code is well coded but after checking the nested elements it blinked in front of me.